How to tell if a charge is accelerating due to gravity or electric field?
Picture yourself floating in deep space. Suppose you observe a charged particle with non-negligible mass accelerating. I wonder if there is a sure-fire way to tell if the charge is accelerating due to gravity or some electric field.
I think it is sufficient to check if the charge is radiating or not. If it is not radiating, then it is accelerating due to gravity. If it is radiating, then it is accelerating due to electric field.

It doesn't matter, what the reason behind the acceleration is. An accelerating particle will emit electromagnetic radiation.

@SamuelAdrianAntz So you are saying it is impossible to discern the cause of acceleration? Is it some kind of equivalence principle?

I think it is, but I'm not yet sure. (In case you've not yet heard of it, the Reissner-Nördstrom metric might be interesting for you. It claims that electric charge also contributes to gravity, but is repulsive.)

@SamuelAdrianAntz if electric charge is contributing to gravity in a repulsive way, does it imply that gravity has become "weaker" in the Reissner Nordstrom metic due to partial cancellation with the electric charge?

@SamuelAdrianAntz accelerating particle need not emit radiation: electrons in its orbit don't radiate in Bohr's model. Although this has nothing to do with QM : if you solve system of Maxwell's and Lorentz equation for two opposite charged particles , you can have stable orbits

If it is accelerating because of an electric field, a nearby test charge with the opposite charge will accelerate the other way. If gravity, the same way.

The core concept to answer this question is that, whether we are speaking about charged particles or any other mechanical system, there is no way to tell the origin (interaction) of a given accelerated motion without additional information. Simply observing an acceleration without the possibility of performing experiments on the accelerating body and the environment is not enough to establish the origin of acceleration.
From a more formal perspective, the previous statements are justified by the difference between knowledge of acceleration as a function of time or of all the parameters the interaction depends on. Notice that such a difference is theory-independent. It remains the same in Classical Mechanics, Special and General Relativity.
From the GR point of view, one could think of using the presence of a radiation field as environment to exclude or not a free-fall motion. Unfortunately, this is not the case. As it has been explained in this answer by A.V.S., a free-falling charge will radiate in any case, because cannot move along a geodesic, due to the presence of the electromagnetic field.

(+1) Let's try a thought experiment. An electron some distance from the sun is being attracted by a moving proton. i.e. the electron experiences electrostatic attraction, magnetic attraction, and gravitational attraction. Now we shift perspective to another perspective (e,g, an astronaut watching the interaction on his moving rocket). According to this astronaut's perspective, the electric and magnetic attraction has transformed in a very specific and complicated manner. But to produce the same net acceleration on the electron as in the other frames, gravity must also transform in the...

...exact same manner as the electric and magnetic forces. Is it mathematically possible for gravity to transform in the exact same complicated manner as the electric and magnetic forces, if it is not using effectively the same mechanism as the Maxwell's equations? i.e. could one reproduce the Maxwell's equations using completely different curvature derivations which has no effective/analogical resemblance to the Maxwell's equations, but yet can transform exactly like the Maxwell's equations?

If you are floating in deep space you cannot see a nearby particle accelerating due to gravity, because gravity will accelerate you as well. So if you see a particle accelerating relative to you, it must be due to an interaction that you don't participate in. That it, electromagnetic.

The gravitational field could be different where you are compared to where the charge is

@BioPhysicist Yes, that's why "deep space" and "nearby" are mentioned explicitly: they form a (locally-)inertial frame of reference. For differences in gravitational field one of these conditions must be broken so to see an acceleration either you must be nearby of a source of gravitation or the particle to be far away.

The OP doesn't use "nearby"

@BioPhysicist Yes, you are right. I added this condition myself because... you know... it is hard to see particles at big distances: they are tiny.

Can you tell which particle is the one being accelerated by electromagnetic forces?

@Mark There is only one observed particle in the question so I don't quite understand what you are talking about.

user13964273 I suspect @Mark may be asking whether the observer can spot whether the passing particle is charged and so being accelerated by electromagnetic forces, or whether the particle is uncharged but the observer is charged and being accelerated in the opposite direction
